# How to override base class css in custom css?

Tags: html, css

Here is the screenshot from chrome dev tools. Here I want to override .ui-menu class and want to increase its with to "20em".
[image]

Here is what I am trying to override it :

```
.menu.ui-menu{

    width:20em;
}
```

I know my css is loading after the base css. Why its not taking the css supplied in custom css class?

**UPDATE**
None of the suggestions provided below worked for me. I have added a div and provided id to div "menu". Now when I use following css , it works :

```
#menu  {

    width:20em;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is the screenshot from console:
[image]

Still unable to increase width of menu that has class "ui-menu". Can someone please help in identifying the selector for "ui-menu" ?

Answer (score 2):

You just need a space between `.menu` and `.ui-menu`, like this:

```
.menu .ui-menu {
    width:20em;
}
```

`.menu.ui-menu` is looking for an element with both the `menu` and `ui-menu` classes, whereas `.menu .ui-menu` is looking for an element with class `ui-menu` that is a child of `menu`.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer to this problem. I am trying to set the css in angular 4 application and all styles are encapsulated by default. to fix this , use following code in component class:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

})
```

Once this is done, all css overriding will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The ui-menu class is on a div, so you could write:

```
div.ui-menu {
    width:20em;
}
```

or

```
.ui-menu {
   width:20em !important;
}
```

or

```
body .ui-menu{
width:20em;
}
```

or something else, all solutions are higher weighted than the ".ui-menu" style as there already is at the moment